# Netgear N600 Router/Modem Access Point

Tags: router, ethernet, wireless-access-point

I have a NetGear N600 Router/Modem that I used to use before I got a new router and modem. I've been wanting to get an ethernet connection into my room without having to route a cable across the walls, making everything look messy. I heard I can make an access point with this router/modem so I can just plug in through the router. I've been doing research and I cant seem to find anything talking about what I want to do. Basically, here is my question: How do I use a router as an ethernet access point to my main router? Or this even possible using some other method? Thanks for any help or feedback.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you are thinking about implementing a network topology more or less like this:

**COMPUTER** <--Ethernet--> **N600** ((--Wireless--)) **SomeOtherWirelessRouter**

If so, you have to set the N600 to *Wireless Repeating* mode, which is accessible by going to **Advanced** tab > **Advanced Setup** on the side bar > **Wireless Repeating**. The rest depends on your current network configuration and what end result you want to get. I suggest you refer to the User's Manual, p. 80, section *Wireless Repeating Function (WDS)*.

For the sake of simplicity, though, I would recommend getting a PCI/PCI-E or a USB WLAN adapter and connect the computer directly to the other wireless router, especially if you don't have at least basic computer networking knowledge. Wireless adapters are very cheap and the configuration will be much simpler -- and therefore a lot less error prone.